# Plotting cdf with ggplot in R

Tags: r, cdf

I have the following simplified data from `csv`

```
owner    num_object_owned
A        120
B        110
C        90
D        30
E        20
...
Z        1
```

I want to plot a cdf curve to show whether object ownership is dominated by a few owners or is it spread out.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- as.data.frame(myData)
ggplot(df, aes(x=num_object_owned))+ 
  stat_ecdf(geom = "step")+
  labs(x = "Number of object hosted")+
  theme_classic()
```

I got the below graph:

[image]

I think I have not plotted correctly, because the x-axis should show the accumulated total number of objects owned right? Or should the x-axis show the owners instead?

Comment: Have you considered a Pareto chart?

Comment: A reprex would help for others to help you.  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/16532098